# Como definir a altura da linha de um Excel no NPOI?

Tags: c#, microsoft-excel, npoi

Eu estou tentando criar uma linha em um arquivo excel através da biblioteca [NPOI](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NPOI/). O problema é que não sei como faço para poder definir um tamanho para a linha. Atualmente, a linha está tampando o conteúdo do texto.

Como  posso fazer para poder definir a altura da linha (se possível altura automática)?

```
private static void CreateHeader(IRow row, List<string> header)
{

    HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();

    ISheet sheet = wb.CreateSheet("Modelo");

    ICellStyle style = wb.CreateCellStyle();

    IRow row = row.CreateRow(0);

    for (int i = 0; i < header.Count; i++)
    {
        ICell cell = row.CreateCell(i);

        cell.SetCellValue(header[i]);

        cell.CellStyle = style;
    }            
}
```

Comment: Já tentou usar o `RowHeight`? No caso `row.RowHeight = 50`, por exemplo, não funcionaria?

Comment: @Evert kkk, eu não tava achando, mas vi que tem o atributo `Height` e `HeightInPoint`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu descobri que existe duas propriedades em `IRow` que permite a definição de altura de linha:

```
IRow row = row.CreateRow(0);
row.Height = 10;
row.HeightInPoints = 20;
```

O erro estava acontecendo quando eu tentava definir através do `row.RowStyle.Height`.